# unable to create object in php and add key/value pair

Tags: php, object

I am trying to create an object in PHP and add a key value pair consisting of an email address for the key and an empty array for the value.  It is not working.  Here is what I've tried.

```
$user[0]['email'] = 'abc@gmail.com';
$obj = new stdClass();
$obj[[$user[0]['email']]=[];
```

I thought this would produce `$obj = {abc@gmail.com:[]}` but it appears blank

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a *Parse error: syntax error* here:

```
$obj[[$user[0]['email']]=[];
     ^
```

However, since it's an object and not an array, use a property.  Curly braces `{}` needed since it's not a valid variable name (not recommended):

```
$user[0]['email'] = 'abc@gmail.com';
$obj = new stdClass();
$obj->{$user[0]['email']}=[];
```

Or create an array and cast it to an object:

```
$user[0]['email'] = 'abc@gmail.com';
(object)$obj[$user[0]['email']]=[];
```

Both yield:

```
stdClass Object
(
    [abc@gmail.com] => Array
        (
        )

)
```